# Swift UINavigationBar background color is different from main one

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar

The problem is that color that I set for the UINavigationBar is different from the same color, which I have set for the layer. I want it to be the same! :) (see image)

AppDelegate.swift

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().shadowImage = UIImage()
    UINavigationBar.appearance().setBackgroundImage(UIImage.imageWithColor(primaryColor), forBarMetrics: .Default)
    UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = primaryColor
    UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFontOfSize(17), NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.whiteColor()]
```

MyController.swift in viewDidLoad()

```
view.backgroundColor = primaryColor
```

Extensions.swift

```
let primaryColor = UIColor(red: 132/255, green: 205/255, blue: 93/255, alpha: 1)
extension UIImage {
    class func imageWithColor(color: UIColor) -> UIImage {
        let rect = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0)
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size)
        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

        CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, color.CGColor)
        CGContextFillRect(context, rect)

        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        return image
    }
}
```

[image]

I think the problem is in UIImage extension. Please help me to solve this problem.

**Solved**

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().translucent = false
```

Comment: i think its the transclucent property of nav bar that does this chnage!

Comment: @Mr.T I was going to suggest the same thing. Give that a try.

Comment: @Mr.T Thanks UINavigationBar.appearance().translucent = false solve problem

Comment: Thanks! in swift 4: navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false

Answer (score 11):

Just `uncheck` the `Translucent` property of `Navigation Bar`. It's worked for me.